# Prolog family tree : check if two persons are from the same family

Tags: tree, prolog

I can check people relationships (uncle, aunt, father, grandfather...) in a tree but now I'd like to know if two people are in the same or a different tree i.e. check if they are from the same 'family'.

The definition of a 'family' is kind of stupid because we all have a common ancestor but that's the exercise I have to do...

[Family tree example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OvUn.png)

I'd like to check that Maurice and Floriane are from the same family...

Comment: It should be enough to check if they have a common ancestor or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
 inSameFamily(Person1, Person2) :-
   ancestor(Person1, CommonAncestor),
   ancestor(Person2, CommonAncestor).
```

Comment: Actually I've tried it but it doesn't always work because the first member of the tree doesn't have any parent(s), so you can't find an ancestor for this person...

Comment: @GuillaumeLeseur It really depends how you decide to define `ancestor/2`. Or you might want to define a predicate that uses `ancestor/2` and also succeeds when the two arguments unify: `same_family(X, X). same_family(X, Y) :- dif(X, Y), ( ancestor(X, Y) ; ancestor(Y, X).`

Comment: I've edited the post, you can check the linked image if you want to know what I mean